# Blazor Component Not Updating UI After Property Change

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a Blazor application in .NET 8 that reads markdown files and displays them on a Blazor page. After the first read, the application sets up an event listener to listen for file changes. The point is to update the Blazor page with the updated markdown file in real time.

The problem is that the first read works fine, but the updating of the property does not display the new text in the markdown on the Blazor page. If I press F5 in the browser, then the new values get printed to the page. So, I have tried reloading the page with StateHasChanged(), await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("location.reload"), and navigationManager.NavigateTo("/", true).

Then I print out the property to the console. The updated text that I want is in the variable, but for some reason, it does not get displayed on the page.

`FileService.cs responsiable for setting up the event listener`

```cs
namespace MarkFlow.FileService;

public class FileService : IFileService
{
    public event Func<Task>? OnFileChanged;
    private readonly string _path = string.Empty;

    public FileService(string path)
    {
        _path = path;
    }

    public async Task<string> ReadFileAsync()
    {
        using var stream = File.OpenRead(_path);
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    public void MonitorFile()
    {
        var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(_path);
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(_path);

        var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher()
        {
            Path = directory,
            Filter = filename,
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName
        };

        watcher.Changed += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);

                OnFileChanged?.Invoke();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        };

        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
}
```

`Home.razor the index page`

```cs
@page "/"

@attribute [StreamRendering(true)]

@using MarkFlow.FileService
@using Markdig

@inject IFileService FileService
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<div class="wrapper">
  @if (@Html is not null)
  {
    @Html
  }
  else
  {
    <p>loading...</p>
  }
</div>

@code {
    private MarkupString? Html { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (FileService is null) return;

        FileService.OnFileChanged += FileChanged;
        FileService.MonitorFile();

        await LoadFileContent();
    }

    private async Task FileChanged()
    {
        await LoadFileContent();

        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/", true);
    }

    private async Task LoadFileContent()
    {
        var markdown = await FileService.ReadFileAsync();
        Html = (MarkupString)(Markdown.ToHtml(markdown));
    }
}
```

I have tried

- navigationManager.NavigateTo("/", true)
- JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("location.reload")
- StateHasChanged()
- Print out the value to see that it updates (it does just not in the Blazor page)

Comment: You need to raise those events on the UI thread. Wrap the logic of `FileChanged` in a call to `InvokeAsync`

Comment: I just tried to add this. Here is the code I wrote `private async Task FileChanged()
    {
        await InvokeAsync(async () =>
        {
            await LoadFileContent();
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }` It did not seem to do anything.

Comment: So what's the project level render mode i.e. `<Routes @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />`

Comment: I used the plate from .NET 8 with the Blazor App. So I do not have a `@rendermode` I have this `<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">` if that help? I think rendermode is .NET 7 and below, but I can be misstaken...

Comment: I have the render mode in the Program.cs set to `app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
`

Answer (score 1):

First it looks like you're using Server Side Rendering with streaming.  That's not going to work for an active page with events.

Here's my `App.Razor` to define `InteractiveServer` as the app render type.  If you want to set it on a page by page basis add `@rendermode InteractiveServer` to the specific page.

```cs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SO77552868.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I've added a `Data.txt` file to the root to use as a demo.

My FileService.  Note how I deal with the Watcher differently and dispose it.

```cs
public class FileService : IDisposable
{
    private string _wwwPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Replace("bin\\Debug\\net8.0\\", ""), "wwwroot");
    private string _filterName => "*.txt";

    private FileSystemWatcher _watcher;

    public event EventHandler<FileSystemEventArgs>? FileSystemChanged;

    public FileService()
    {
        _watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(_wwwPath, _filterName);
        _watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName;
        _watcher.Changed += OnChanged;
        _watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetFileTextAsync(string fileName)
    {
        var _fullFileName = Path.Combine(_wwwPath, fileName);
        var file = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(_fullFileName);
        return file;
    }

    private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Changed: {e.FullPath}");
        this.FileSystemChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _watcher.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And my Demo page.  Note wiring up the event (and disposing it) and re-reading the file and updataing the UI.

```cs
@page "/counter"
@inject FileService FileService
@implements IDisposable
<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<div class="bg-dark text-white" m-2 p-2>
@_text
</div>

@code {
    private string? _text;
    private string _fileName = "Data.txt";

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.FileService.FileSystemChanged += OnFileSystemUpdated;
        await this.GetTextAsync();
    }

    private async Task GetTextAsync()
    {
        _text = await this.FileService.GetFileTextAsync(_fileName);
    }

    private async void OnFileSystemUpdated(object? sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Name == _fileName)
        {
            await this.GetTextAsync();
            await this.InvokeAsync(this.StateHasChanged);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.FileService.FileSystemChanged -= OnFileSystemUpdated;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the rendermode pointed out by @MrC aka Shaun Curtis.

In .NET 8 the you can set the render mode as part of its definition with `@rendermode InteractiveServer`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#apply-a-render-mode-to-a-component-definition

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).